# Subprocess code to convert unix text file to windows

Tags: python, unix, awk, terminal, subprocess

I wrote a program to convert unix text files to be readable in Windows. The program executes inside a Linux machine. The Python code I use to convert is:

```
subprocess.Popen('''awk 'sub("$", "\r")' unix_{0}.txt > windows_{0}.txt'''.format(file_name))
```

Both unix and windows text file are identical while viewing on a Linux machine. When I try to open the windows text file in a Windows machine, it is unable to locate the file.

Using the following line inside terminal works:

```
awk 'sub("$", "\r")' unix.txt > windows.txt
```

But somehow it did not translate correctly when using it in my program. Is there something wrong with the way I used subprocess?

Comment: it seems you have different file names, In terminal you have unix.txt  and windows, but in code you have unix_{0}.txt > windows_{0}.txt

Comment: @galaxyan I was just formatting inside my code to make it easier to get the file. I am still using the same files files in both situations. Do you think formatting would change something?